# php MissingKeyMissing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make an HTTP request using PHP's cURL to fetch data from a server. The server requires authentication, and I'm providing the necessary credentials in the request headers. However, I'm encountering a warning "Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value", even though I believe I've included all required parameters.

simple data json url

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "expires": 1710853210.524307,
  "basemap_lines": {
    "url": "style.json?t={time}",
    "auth": "Key-Pair-Id=K3B6LIRZIHY0OC&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kMWRkaWZ4Nm0zMzgxNi5mb3JlZmxpZ2h0LmNvbS90aWxlc2VydmVyL3Jlc291cmNlcy9iYXNlbWFwX2xpbmVzLyoiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE3MTA4NTMyMTB9fX1dfQ__&Signature=2jgr~n5ykcw4uf39sHjva3liXJsTHbVG353BhpRvEZPGtTkFxb13V0nRGddUxXD2QulVQKjA-R-vrD6eHrpYrDJKrBvPJZ0U1t7b51QTS3VaMBg7q8rGBf4SV0IiTDKfeCStoGSxKPNMbVVzLdzjILbkeE7oEDy-iSFgEKdE828OO1H2EW8SRBu5GtNxFAoZ9p2gZilIN6qA1AyptvKDgx735J79WUZqoJHehwG58n1fxpKRG3kWLi8-1NqEuhaE-IJnRCQ1WyyoOcDVgcD5vxnfBips0p3ke~NKDkOBojUCmAM9Qrw1c8ey9unQmVEvVbOP0RvgdvuT4iWtXSnjRg__"
  }
}
```

when accessing to URL of data JSON auth it will change auto .

code

```
<?php

function fetchLinesData($url, $auth, $keyPairId = null) {
    // Initialize cURL session
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: ' . $auth,
        // Add any other required headers here
    ));

    // If Key-Pair-Id is provided, include it as a query parameter
    if ($keyPairId !== null) {
        $url .= '?Key-Pair-Id=' . urlencode($keyPairId);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    }

    // Execute cURL session
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close cURL session
    curl_close($ch);

    // Return the response
    return $response;
}

// Define the URL
$baseUrl = 'data.json';

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute cURL session
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL session
curl_close($ch);

// Decode the JSON response
$data = json_decode($response, true);

// Extract the URL and auth from the response
$linesUrl = $data['basemap_lines']['url'];
$linesAuth = $data['basemap_lines']['auth'];

// Check if Key-Pair-Id is provided in the response
$keyPairId = isset($data['basemap_lines']['key_pair_id']) ? $data['basemap_lines']['key_pair_id'] : null;

// Fetch lines data using the function
$linesData = fetchLinesData($linesUrl, $linesAuth, $keyPairId);

// Output the lines data
echo $linesData;

?>
```

return `MissingKeyMissing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value`

Comment: The `basemap_lines` object in your JSON does not have any property with the key `key_pair_id`, so you end up with `null` for $keyPairId here.

Comment: what about `    "auth": "Key-Pair-Id=K3B6LIRZIHY0OC&" in  object in your JSON?
`

Comment: The key of that entry is `auth`; not `key_pair_id` which you tried to access. You need to access the former, and then decode that using `parse_str` (it appears to be a query string parameter format.)